# Not-a-Number error in javascript. Can't find where things don't work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently learning javascript just to play around and make a few little games in. Right now I'm doing an ad-hoc sort of frogger. I've got a list of objects (the "tangos", opposition), and they are currently subjected to two problems:
The y number that gets generated in reset is being reported by my debug output as NaN.
They will not render on the canvas.
I hate to slap the entire source code on my post, but in order to get the full context of the issue it is slightly necessary (the variable names are atrocious, you know how it can be sometimes):

```
var buffer=35; //collision buffer
var magic32 = 32; //sprite height & width. again, variable names....
var WIN_CONST = 470; //how far the player has to go to advance

// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// Background image
var bgReady = false;
var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.onload = function () {
    bgReady = true;
};
bgImage.src = "background.png";

//background music
var audReady = false;
var audFile = new Audio();
audFile.onload = function(){
    audReady=true;
}
audFile.src = "bizoop.jpeg.mp3";
//TODO: Actually implement this
audFile.addEventListener("ended", function(){
    this.currentTime = 0;
    this.play();
}, false)

// Player image
var pReady = false;
var pImage = new Image();
pImage.onload = function () {
    pReady = true;
};
pImage.src = "hero.png";

// opposition image
var mReady = false;
var mImage = new Image();
mImage.onload = function () {
    mReady = true;
};
mImage.src = "monster.png";

// Game objects
var player = {
    speed: 256, // movement in pixels per second
    x : 0, //start at 0, 1/2*whole
    y : canvas.height / 2,
    totalX : 0
};
var opposition = {
    speed: 1
};
//var list = []; list.push({ date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 });
//gen a list of tangos
var tangos = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
    tangos.push({spped:1,x:0,y:0});
}
var oppositionsCaught = 0;
var difficulty=1;

// Handle keyboard controls
var keysDown = {};

addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
}, false);

addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
    delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
}, false);

// Reset the game when the player touches an opposition
var reset = function () {
//reposition player and create new opposition/tangos
    player.x = 0;
    player.y = canvas.height / 2;

    for (var i = 0; i < tangos.length; i++) { 
        tangos[i].x = i * 50 + 50; //todo: logic
        tangos[i].y = magic32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64)); //tweak later
        if (i >=5){
            tangos[i].north = true;
        }
        console.warn(tangos[i].x+","+tangos[i].y);//prints a normal float for Y
    }
};

var levelup = false;
var update = function (modifier) {
    if (levelup){
        reset();
        difficulty ++;
        levelup = false;
    }
    if (38 in keysDown) { // Player holding up
        player.y -= player.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (40 in keysDown) { // Player holding down
        player.y += player.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (37 in keysDown) { // Player holding left
        player.x -= player.speed * modifier;
    }
    if (39 in keysDown) { // Player holding right
        player.x += player.speed * modifier;
        player.totalX++;
    }
    //is he out of bounds?
    if (player.x <= 0){
            player.x=3;
        }
    else if (player.x >= canvas.width - buffer){
            player.x=canvas.width - buffer;
        }
    if (player.y <= 0){
            player.y=3;
        }
    else if (player.y >= canvas.height - buffer){
            player.y=canvas.height - buffer;
        }

    for (var i = 0; i < tangos.length; ++i){

        var opp = tangos[i];
        // is opposition out of bounds ON Y axis only
        if (opp.y <= 0 && opp.north){
            opp.y = 512;//canvas.height + buffer + magic32;
            console.warn("Just paralaxed an opposition to NORTHBOUND "+opp.y);
        }
        if (opp.y >= canvas.height - buffer && !opp.north){
            opp.y=-(buffer + magic32);
            console.warn("Just paralaxed an opposition to SOUTHBOUND "+opp.y);
        }   

        if (opp.north){
            opp.y-=opp.speed * modifier;
        }else {
            opp.y+=opp.speed * modifier;
        }

            // Are they touching?
        if (
            player.x <= (opp.x + magic32)
            && opp.x <= (player.x + magic32)
            && player.y <= (opp.y + magic32)
            && opp.y <= (player.y + magic32)
        ) {
            reset(); //game is over lol
            player.totalX = 0;
        }
    }


    if (player.x > WIN_CONST){
        levelup = true;
    }
}

// Draw everything
var render = function () {
    if (bgReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
    }

    if (pReady) {
        ctx.drawImage(pImage, player.x, player.y);
    }

    if (mReady) {
        //TODO: this for all tangos
        for (var i = 0; i < tangos.length; ++i){
            ctx.drawImage(mImage, tangos[i].x, tangos[i].y);
        }
    }
    if (audReady){
        audFile.play();
    }

    // Score
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
    ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
    ctx.textAlign = "left";
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.fillText("Distance Traveled: "+player.totalX, 32, 32);
    ctx.fillText("Level: " + difficulty, 32, 64);
    ctx.fillText("Player: "+ player.x +", "+player.y, 32, 96);
    ctx.fillText("1st Tango: "+ tangos[0].x +"," +tangos[0].y, 32, 128);
    ctx.fillText("9th Tango: "+tangos[9].x +","+tangos[9].y, 32, 160);

};

// The main game loop
var main = function () {
    var now = Date.now();
    var delta = now - then;

    update(delta / 1000);
    render();

    then = now;

    // Request to do this again ASAP
    requestAnimationFrame(main);
};

// Cross-browser support for requestAnimationFrame
var w = window;
requestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame;

// Let's play this game!
var then = Date.now();
reset();
main();
```

Comment: [Learn how to use your browser's developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging), step through the code step by step and follow how `y` changes. Being able to debug the code you write is an absolute essential skill. Then, once you find the offending operation and wonder why this happens or how to fix it, you can ask a question about it.

Comment: _' I hate to slap the entire source code on my post,'_ - then don't. You should narrow the problem to the code that's affected and post that. See [this entry in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `ctx.fillText("1st Tango: "+ tangos[0].x +"," +tangos[0].y, 32, 128);
    ctx.fillText("9th Tango: "+tangos[9].x +","+tangos[9].y, 32, 160);`

Comment: `tangos[i].y = magic32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));` make sure `canvas.height` is not a NaN (by the way there's a method [isNan](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a spelling mistake :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
    tangos.push({spped:1,x:0,y:0});// should be speed
}
```